# PowerMockito null pointer when trying to use ApplicationContext

Tags: java, junit4, powermock

I have a class name ServiceLocator

```
public class ServiceLocator implements ApplicationContextAware {
    private transient ApplicationContext _applicationContext;
    private static ServiceLocator _instance = new ServiceLocator();

    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) 
                            throws BeansException {
        _instance._applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    public static ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
        return _instance._applicationContext;
    }

    public static Object findService(String serviceName) {
        return _instance._applicationContext.getBean(serviceName);
    }
}
```

I am trying to use that class to find Service into Approver class methods

```
public class ApproverService extends AbstractDataService implements  IApproverService {
     public void updateCompletedInboxStatus(String status) {
        IInboxService inboxService = (IInboxService)ServiceLocator.findService("inboxService");
        InboxItem inboxItem = inboxService.getInboxItem("test");
        inboxItem.setWorkItemStatus(status);
        inboxService.saveInboxItem(inboxItem);
    }
}
```

With that code i am trying to write Junit with PowerMockRunner

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ApproverService.class})
public class ApproverServiceTest  {
    @InjectMocks
    ApproverService approverService;

    @Mock
    IInboxService inboxService;

    @Mock
    ServiceLocator serviceLocator;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void updateCompletedInboxStatus() {
        RequestAccessHeader reqHdr = new RequestAccessHeader();
        reqHdr.setRequestStatus(AccessConstants.REQ_STATUS_HOLD_INT);
        String status = "test";

        PowerMockito.mockStatic(ServiceLocator.class);
        when(serviceLocator.findService("inboxService")).thenReturn(inboxService);

        approverService.updateCompletedInboxStatus(status);
    }
}
```

But I am getting null pointer

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at com.alnt.fabric.common.ServiceLocator.findService(ServiceLocator.java:25)
>       at com.alnt.access.approver.service.ApproverServiceTest.updateCompletedInboxStatus(ApproverServiceTest.java:80)

Please help me to find the solution for that issue.

Comment: it doesn't look right: the exception comes from the origianal code of ServiceLocator.findService which implies that the method call is not mocked.  Have you tried `when(ServiceLocator.findService(...)).thenReturn(inboxService)` instead?

Comment: yes tried with both ways but no luck

Comment: You really _really_ shouldn't be mixing `ServiceLocator` and Spring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The static method is obviously not mocked.

The problem is most probably because you haven't add the to-be-mocked class in `@PrepareForTest`

Change it to `@PrepareForTest({ApproverService.class, ServiceLocator.class})`

---

Off-topics:

Although it compiles, calling static method by instance reference is not a good practice.  Therefore the line should be `when(ServiceLocator.findService(...)).thenReturn(inboxService)`.

Another problem is, you tried to use Singleton pattern but in wrong way.  A singleton is suppose to return you an instance so the caller can call its instance method.  Your `findService` is preferably an instance method and to be called as `ServiceLocator.getInstance().findService(...)`.  To further improve, unless you really need it to be a singleton, you should make it a normal object instance and inject to objects that need it (given you are already using Spring, I see no reason making a Singleton)

Comment: I don't think we can assume that `ApproverService` preparation is not used in other tests (although it is reasonable to assume), that's why I was leaving it there intentionally.

Answer (score 0):

The setup for the static method is not mocked correctly

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ServiceLocator.class}) //Prepare static class for mock
public class ApproverServiceTest  {    
    @Mock
    IInboxService inboxService;

    @Mock
    InboxItem item;

    @InjectMocks
    ApproverService approverService;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void updateCompletedInboxStatus() {
        //Arrange
        String status = "test";

        PowerMockito.mockStatic(ServiceLocator.class);
        when(ServiceLocator.findService("inboxService")) //<-- NOTE static call
            .thenReturn(inboxService);

        when(inboxService.getInboxItem("test")).thenReturn(item);

        //Act
        approverService.updateCompletedInboxStatus(status);

        //...
    }
}
```

#### Reference [Mocking Static Method](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Mockito#mocking-static-method)

The subject under test should actually be refactored to avoid the service locator anit-pattern / code smell and should follow explicit dependency principle via constructor injection.

```
public class ApproverService extends AbstractDataService implements  IApproverService {
    private  IInboxService inboxService;

    @Autowired
    public ApproverService(IInboxService inboxService){
        this.inboxService = inboxService;
    }

    public void updateCompletedInboxStatus(String status) {        
        InboxItem inboxItem = inboxService.getInboxItem("test");
        inboxItem.setWorkItemStatus(status);
        inboxService.saveInboxItem(inboxItem);
    }
}
```

That way the subject class is genuine about what it needs to perform its function correctly,

And the test can then be refactored accordingly

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)    
public class ApproverServiceTest  {    
    @Mock
    IInboxService inboxService;

    @Mock
    InboxItem item;

    @InjectMocks
    ApproverService approverService;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void updateCompletedInboxStatus() {
        //Arrange
        String status = "test";    
        when(inboxService.getInboxItem("test")).thenReturn(item);

        //Act
        approverService.updateCompletedInboxStatus(status);

        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: I have posted (and deleted) a similar answer, coz I do remember that the compiler will compile `instance.staticMethod` to `ClassName.staticMethod`, which should give identical behaviour.  However I do believe the static method is not mocked correct coz from the stack trace, the original code is still invoked